# How to resolve object reference error in lambda expression of linq in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, linq, lambda

I am working on WPF application. In which I am trying to fetch records from list as per required condition. But when there is no any record found then it's giving me object reference not found error.

```
var recordList = _outputVariables.ToList().Where(X => X.symbolName == _symbolName).ToList();
if (recordList != null)
{
       //more coding...
}
```

so as shown in code when _outputVariables have no any record match as per _symbolName then it's giving error of `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` and `X was null.`. So how can I handle this issue ? please help for it.

Comment: `.Where(X => X?.symbolName == _symbolName)` or `.Where(X => X!= null && X.symbolName == _symbolName)`

Comment: What is `record1`?

Comment: Where(X => (X.symbolName != null) && (X.symbolName == _symbolName))

Comment: sorry by mistake it's written there actually record1 is recordList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the null-conditional operator that was introduced in C#6 (and don't call `ToList()` more than once):

```
var recordList = _outputVariables?.Where(X => X?.symbolName == _symbolName).ToList();
if (recordList != null)
{
    //more coding...
}
```

Comment: _outputVariables are operating from other methods also for insert and delete operation. So if I am not mentioning ToList with _outputVariables then it's showing error like List is modified. So I am using there ToList with _outputVariables. I would like to here suggestion if I can modify it better?

Comment: @HardikRPatel: If "other method" means "other threads" you should synchronize the access to the list. Calling `ToList` won't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below as well

```
 if (_outputVariables != null && _outputVariables.Count > 0)
            {
               var recordList = _outputVariables.Where(X => X != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(X.symbolName) && X.symbolName == _symbolName);

            }
```

Comment: This will throw if `X` is null.

Comment: @Ajax: It will still throw if `X` is `null` and now you are calling `ToList()` not only two but three times...

Comment: @mm8 is it ok now? I have tested it as well. I just want to make it with normal way

Answer (score 0):

`var recordList = _outputVariables.ToList().Where(X => X.symbolName == _symbolName).ToList();`

You currently loop through `_outputVariables`, but if it's `null` this will give an error, because `null` does not have a `.ToList()`. So you should add a `?` after your `_outputVariables`, so it will return `null` instead of an exception when it's null.

Same goes for `X`. If `X` is `null` and you try to get the property `symbolName`, you will get an error, because `null` doesn't have a property called `symbolName`. So you want to add a `?` here too. So it will return `null` instead of an exception.

Leaving you with: `var recordList = _outputVariables?.ToList().Where(X => X?.symbolName == _symbolName).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
if(_outputVariables!=null)
{
var recordList = _outputVariables.Where(X => X.symbolName ==_symbolName).ToList();
}
if (recordList != null)
{
       //more coding...
}
```